# Iphone 4S is displaying black screen but is still on. Can't restart because lock button is broken

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to fix my brother's phone. The screen is completely unresponsive. I tried swiping around to try getting the passcode wrong to see if it would vibrate to no avail. The phone's lock button is broken, so I can't restart it that way, and it was never used with a computer, so when I tried to plug it in and fix it that way, iTunes asks me to confirm that I want to allow this device access by clicking something on the phone (which obviously I cannot do). I read somewhere that the LCD connector may be loose. Could this be the problem? Is there any way to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds a lot like that to me. You could disconnect and reconnect the LCD cable yourself, if you are comfortable with opening up the iPhone. You would need a special iPhone screwdriver (one with 5-point star tip, AKA pentalobe), which can really only be found online.

You could also take it in to a repair shop, if any are around you, but whatever you choose don't over pay, as **a *working* iPhone 4s is only worth around $100.**

Comment: @Eleyna By the way, ifixit.com is a great place for repair guides.